# Need to downgrade a package with many dependents

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, synaptic, downgrade

In order to get a working low-power video card setup I decided to use a custom xserver from Andrikos:ppa.  It worked well, but when the official release caught up to the bug fixes I dried to drop the PPA packages and there are some of them I can not get rid of.

Packages were from here: https://launchpad.net/~andrikos/

I know how to down grade packages using Synaptic (Force Version...) and apt-get package=version.  However, with some of the packages there are so many dependencies that is is no feasible to uninstall them all (as Synaptic wants to do).

This is what I would like to do:

```
sudo apt-get install -f libncurses5=5.9-10ubuntu4 libncursesw5=5.9-10ubuntu4 libncurses5:i386=5.9-10ubuntu4 libncursesw5:i386=5.9-10ubuntu4 libtinfo5=5.9-10ubuntu4 libtinfo5:386=5.9-10ubuntu4
```

But I get several hundreds of packages that have to be removed to meet the request.  Does anyone have any tips on removing the PPA packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ppa-purge` would solve your problem.

Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then run:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:andrikos/ppa
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! I did have to do `sudo ppa-purge ppa:andrikos/ppa` to get it to remove.  Just for my information, is this application a script for existing apt-get functionality?  If so, can I do the same operation without ppa-purge?

Comment: @CodePoet Hmm. I'm not sure. I'll do a little research on that. I fixed the command in the answer so that someone else won't have the same problem :)

Comment: @CodePoet Yes, the whole thing is one big (well, rather big) bash script. You can take a look [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ppa-purge/ppa-purge/ubuntu/view/head:/ppa-purge). So technically you *could* do the same on your own, although someone obviously thought it was too much work since they wrote this ;)