# How to downgrade a package using dpkg

Tags: package-management, dpkg, downgrade

I want to downgrade some packages. I search and find [How to downgrade packages on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292314/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu) and this [Need to downgrade a package with many dependents](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360687/need-to-downgrade-a-package-with-many-dependents) and this [How to Downgrade a Package via apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get).

But i just want to do it with dpkg.

Could i just run `dpkg -i package-name`? If yes then what will be done with the highest already insatlled version?!

Comment: Are you trying to downgrade a package in particular?

Comment: I'm trying to downgrade many packages in an offline pc. I have the .deb files of those packages

Answer (score 13):

You can do that with

```
dpkg -i package-file.deb
```

This will replace any other version of `package-file.deb` that already is installed.

As `dpkg` can't resolve package dependencies it will just complain if you need to downgrade other packages, and you'll have to do that manually.

Note that downgrading isn't officially supported and may cause problems with some packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

> apt install packagename=version

To restore packages to a version in the archive.